# Amazing algebra problem: prove algebraically that the antiderivatives found out by different methods are same.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If
$$
f(x)=\ln x+2x-2\left(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x}\right)-2\ln\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right)
$$
$$
or f(x)=\ln\left(\frac{x}{2x+1+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}\right)+2\left(x-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x}\right)
$$
and
$$
g(x) = 2\ln\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x}}{2x+1+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{2x+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x}+1}-1
$$
then prove f(x)=g(x)

Both functions arise from evaluation of the integral I=
$\int \frac{dx}{\left(x+\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}\right)^{2}}$=$\int(2+\frac{1}{x}-2\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x}})dx$
.To get I=f(x)+c, substitute $t=x^{2}+x$.
The constant -1 in f(x) is found by plotting f(x)-g(x) on a graphing calculator.

I can not convince myself that the two functions are the same.

Comment: By 'non algebraically', I suppose you mean that to prove $f'(x)=g'(x)$ and, e.g., $f(1)=g(1)$ it is not an accepted technique.

Comment: By the way, you can prove that $\ln\left(\frac{x}{2x+1+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}\right)= 2\ln\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x}}{2x+1+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}\right)$ and that $2(x-\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x})=\frac{1}{2x+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x}+1}-1$ are both true.
Manipulating the RHS of the first equality  $2\ln\left(\frac{x+\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x}}{2x+1+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}}\right)=\ln\frac{(x+\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1+x})^2}{(2x+1+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1})^2}=\ldots$ will get you to the desired conclusion for the first summand.

Comment: For the second equality, just add the summands in the RHS to get a single fraction and rationalize the denominator multiplying numerator and denominator by $2x+1-2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x+1}$.
You may want to use WolframAlpha to do the computations.